# ORA-01722: invalid number - type issue in oracle

Tags: oracle, sqldatatypes

I have a problem with data type and relationship between two tables
let's assume I have two tables as shown in the image

- First table: **Attached _file**. The **ID** coulmn is **number**
- Second table: **FN_Transaction**. the **ID** coulmn is **varchar(20)**

[image]

The ID in FN_Transaction has four cases

- ID is null which means there is no attached file
- ID has text as **'No'** cell which means there is no attached file
- ID starts with 0, but it will be equaled ID in Attached _file table such as **01222 = 1222**
- ID in FN_Transaction equals ID in Attached _file without 0 such as **2344 = 2344**

let's see the query

```
with docs as 
  (
SELECT
ID,
COUNT(type) fileNo,              
MAX(Date) date
FROM
Attached_file
GROUP BY
ID
)

Select 
InvoiceNo, 
fileNo,
date,
Amount
from 
FN_transaction x1
left join  docs x2 on 
(Trim(x1.ID) = x2.ID)
```

the error that I got

Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P034, (1)
ORA-01722: invalid number
12801. 00000 -  "error signaled in parallel query server %s"
*Cause:    A parallel query server reached an exception condition.
*Action:   Check the following error message for the cause, and consult
your error manual for the appropriate action.

Do you have an idea about how to handle this type of column?
Please advise

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `default on conversion error` clause in `TO_NUMBER` function (introduced in 12.2) as follows:

```
ON ( to_number(X1.ID default null on conversion error) = X2.ID )
```

Note that `01222` will be automatically converted to a number `1222`. character `NO` will be converted to `NULL` because of `default on conversion error` and it will not match the join condition(which satisfies your requirement)

Comment: Thank you for replying, I tried to apply this syntax but I got another error. so I am not sure is the error due to parenthesis or my old version

Comment: 00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"

Comment: Version 4.1.3.20